# How do I check if an HTML input name has a certain value with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

In my website I am processing an HTML form currently with PHP, but I need to do it with JavaScript. With JavaScript how do I check if an HTML input name has a certain value?

Basically I need to do the equivalent of this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['reportsubmit'])) {
    $radio = $_POST['report'];
    if ($radio == 'customer') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#customer">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'item') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#item">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'department') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#department">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'person') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#person">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    }
} else if (isset($_POST['customersubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
} else if (isset($_POST['itemsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
} else if (isset($_POST['departmentsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
} else if (isset($_POST['personsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gordmart MIS Reports</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Main.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="report">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <h3>Would you like to view a report grouped by customers, items, sales departments, or sales people?</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF;"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="customer"><p>Customers</p>
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="item"><p>Items Sold</p>
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="department"><p>Sales Departments</p>
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="person"><p>Sales People</p>
                <input type="submit" name="reportsubmit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="customer">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <h3>Would you like to view a cumulative report of all customers, or a single report of just one?</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="customer" value="all"><p>All</p>
                <input type="radio" name="customer" value="one"><p>One</p><br>
                <input type="submit" name="customersubmit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="item">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <h3>Would you like to view a cumulative report of all sales items, or a single report of just one?</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="item" value="all"><p>All</p>
                <input type="radio" name="item" value="one"><p>One</p><br>
                <input type="submit" name="itemsubmit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="department">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <h3>Would you like to view a cumulative report of all sales departments, or a single report of just one?</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="department" value="all"><p>All</p>
                <input type="radio" name="department" value="one"><p>One</p><br>
                <input type="submit" name="departmentsubmit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="person">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <h3>Would you like to view a cumulative report of all sales people, or a single report of just one?</h3>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="person" value="all"><p>All</p>
                <input type="radio" name="person" value="one"><p>One</p><br>
                <input type="submit" name="personsubmit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" class="frame" id="redirect">
        <div data-role="header">
            <?php include("Header.php");?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" id="main">
            <?php echo $redirect;?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But with JavaScript. So the part I would need to do the equivalent of is specifically this part:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['reportsubmit'])) {
    $radio = $_POST['report'];
    if ($radio == 'customer') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#customer">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'item') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#item">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'department') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#department">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'person') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#person">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    }
} else if (isset($_POST['customersubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
} else if (isset($_POST['itemsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
} else if (isset($_POST['departmentsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
} else if (isset($_POST['personsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
}
?>
```

So basically I need to know how to read an HTML input name and value, and see if the HTML input name has a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var element = document.getElementById("textid");

var value = element.value;

var name = element.name;
```

## Second solution

As I can see your code has multiple element with same name so either change them to have different names and use the below mentioned solution (just for design sake).

or give them an id and use the first solution.

```
var x=document.getElementsByName("report");


for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
alert(x[i].name);

}
```

Comment: Is "textid" just "textid" or should I replace something there?

Comment: Its the id of the element you want the details for.It can be anything

Comment: So what would it be if I wanted it for this:

    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF;'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>" method="post">
     <input type="radio" name="report" value="customer"><p>Customers</p>
     <input type="radio" name="report" value="item"><p>Items Sold</p>
     <input type="radio" name="report" value="department"><p>Sales Departments</p>
     <input type="radio" name="report" value="person"><p>Sales People</p>
     <input type="submit" name="reportsubmit" value="Submit">
    </form>

Comment: I'm looking to see if one name, which is on multiple inputs, has a certain value. A name can only have one value. I'm seeing if a name has a certain value. How do I see if a name has a certain value. By the way the code above does absolutely nothing.